# Получение названий всех столбцов не отмеченных атрибутом auto_increment в PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql

Как создать select, чтобы получить имена всех колонок не обозначенных атрибутом auto_increment (предпочтительно). Как отфильтровать ResultSet так чтобы не было таких полей?

Answer (score 1):

Таким образом можно получить все не autoIncrement поля таблицы:

```
DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet columns = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, "schema_name", "table_name", null);
List<String> notAutoIncrementColumns = new ArrayList<>();
while (columns.next()) {
    boolean autoIncrement = columns.getBoolean("IS_AUTOINCREMENT");
    if (!autoIncrement) {
        String columnName = columns.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
        notAutoIncrementColumns.add(columnName);
    }
}
```